# Google Sheets Formula - Trying to Sum, based on multiple cell criteria

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, conditional-formatting

I am looking for help with Google Sheets formula.

The formula I need is -

If A:A=LG and F:F=Indexed then sum the total of P:P for all of those instances.

If A:A=PG and F:F=Indexed then sum the total of P:P for all of those instances.

If A:A=LG and F:F=Fixed then sum the total of P:P for all of those instances.

If A:A=PG and F:F=Fixed then sum the total of P:P for all of those instances.

for example this formula SHOULD make **JV Fixed = $27,000**
and **JV Indexed = $160,000**

Here is a condensed version of my actual sheet,

[image]

Im sure this is simple for someone, but I'm not that great with formulas :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to SUM() a column based on criteria, then `SUMIF()` or `SUMIFS()` would get you what you want. In this example you could use `SUMIFS()`

`=SUMIFS(P:P, A:A, "PG", F, "Indexed")` - this gives you a SUM of values in P where Column A = "PG" and Column F = "Indexed". You could extend these criteria for as many filters as you need.

You'd then change this formula for the various criteria you want.

For more info, check out the [Help Center article on SUMIFS()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3238496)